# Ошибка "bot can't send messages to bots" при нажатии на только что созданную кнопку в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, inline

создаю первого бота и возникла проблемма с кнопками, вот код:

```
    def helper(message):
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ok, "+name+", let's find some apartments for you!")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    small_key = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Small', callback_data = 'small')
    keyboard.add(small_key)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'What size do you prefer?', reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)

def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'small':
        bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, "12321")
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии а кнопку в консоле выводится ошибка (**init**.py:667 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots"
уже пробовал /revoke бота четер ботфазера, не спасает.

Answer (score 2):

```
bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, "12321")
```

В этой строке Вы посылаете сообщение от бота к боту замените на

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "12321")
```

старайтесь использовать chat.id а не from_user.id так как chat.id всегда будет содержать id пользователя с которым работает бот а вот from_user.id может содержать ID самого бота это особо актуально для inline режима. А сообщения от бота к боту запрещены в телеграмме!